# How do I get find my "CheckBox" item that is in the ItemTemplate?

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I have the following (very simple) ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl Name="BlahList" ItemsSource="{Binding Blah}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="MyCheckBox" Content="{Binding Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In code, I would like to do the following:

```
foreach (var dahCurrentItem in BlahList.Items)
{
    var ItemCheckBox = BlahList.GimmeMyControl(dahCurrentItem, "MyCheckBox")

    // I'm going to do something with the check box here...
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firstly, don't if there's any way you can avoid it. It's much cleaner to bind the various properties of the `CheckBox` to your view model rather than trying to pull them out manually.

That said, if you need to get to your `CheckBox`, you can should be able to use code like this:

```
var container = _itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dahCurrentItem) as FrameworkElement;
var checkBox = container.FindName("MyCheckBox") as CheckBox;
```

Comment: You sir, are beautiful! - I agree with your statement, but in this case I'm doing a "Check All" and "Check None" type function... I realize I could have the "isChecked" bound to some array, and then re-update bindings... but just foreaching and checking is lazier... I mean.. easier :) Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I had to take away the "answered" check box... because I'm only getting "NULL". I imagine this is really close, but there must be something small missing.

Comment: What should be done finally to not get null when doing the `FindName`?

Answer (score 29):

OK, Kent gets the credit, but it was only *mostly* right :)

```
// This part was good:
var container = _itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dahCurrentItem) as FrameworkElement;
```

but... the second part would return null, so it had to be as follows:

```
var checkBox = _itemsControl.ItemTemplate.FindName("MyCheckBox", container) as CheckBox;
```

His code looked like it should have worked, but for my case, I had to do this instead.

Comment: I don't have a `FindName` method on the ItemTemplate(also there seems to be an extra `)` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of capturing a container that houses your ItemsControl's item:

```
       CheckBox checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

        foreach (var item in MembersItemsControl.Items)
        {
            var container = 
MembersItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as FrameworkElement;

            UserInformation user = container.DataContext as UserInformation;

            bool isMale = true;
            if (user.sex == isMale && checkbox.IsChecked.Value == true)
            {
                container.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code that Kent and Timothy supplied, but this additional line was also needed for me.

The whole code snippet goes:

```
var container = _itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dahCurrentItem) as FrameworkElement;
container.ApplyTemplate()
var checkBox = _itemsControl.ItemTemplate.FindName("MyCheckBox", container) as CheckBox;
```

Cheers!

Comment: I re-framed the answer to not look like a question. I wanted only to add the line that was not in previous answers. Also, as you said I don't have enough reputation for a comment...

Comment: answers need to be standalone, they must not depend on other answers