# Visible name in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid with a column containing a `ComboBox`. I've set the `Name` for my combobox, but this name is not visible in code, why?

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.TemplateColumn>
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Name="mex" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=combolist}"
                              SelectionChanged="status_SelectionChanged" Height="auto" Width="Auto">
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGrid.TemplateColumn>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In C# code `mex` is empty, not visible, why?

I tried `x:Name="mex"` as well, but it is still not visible.

c#:

```
mex.ItemsSource = dt;
```

undifined `mex`

Comment: Where is this `ComboBox`? MainWindow.xaml? App.xaml? A resource dictionary?

Comment: ComboBox insert datagrid

Comment: That's not terribly specific. Could you show us more code? I'm pretty sure I know what your problem is, but I am not 100% certain with your snippet.

Comment: @MexVl I made an edit to your question based on what you wrote which I hope will clarify the question. Feel free to roll it back if it is not correct. Also, can you post the C# code you are using to access `mex`?

Comment: You should have a lot of these combobox : one per column. which one did you expect your variable would have referenced ?

Answer (score 3):

A `DataGridColumn` is never actually in the Logical or Visual Tree; it is always a `DataGridRow` with `DataGridCells`, since they are automatically created for each row in the DataGrid.

The only way to reach your component is to build a complex Binding or find it using a Logical or Visual Tree helper.

BTW you should set your `ItemsSource` of your `ComboBox` through `Bindings` to available data from your row. You can't create bindings using `ElementName` within a `DataGridTemplateColumn` as again it is not in the Logical or Visual Tree.

I found an interesting link that explains the Visual Tree of a DataGrid: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/14/wpf-datagrid-dissecting-the-visual-layout.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly reference elements when they are stored within an items template. Normally you'd want to allow the viewmodel to handle the bindings by setting the datacontext to the parent object and then allow the elements within the items template to pick this up. However based upon your question it looks as if you are attempting to do this directly from code behind.

Here are two similar questions and solutions for setting up the datacontext of an item as well as referencing an element within an items template. Hope this helps

[Access parent DataContext from DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404707/access-parent-datacontext-from-datatemplate)

and

[WPF - ItemsControl - How do I get find my "CheckBox" item that is in the ItemTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603203/wpf-itemscontrol-how-do-i-get-find-my-checkbox-item-that-is-in-the-itemtem)

Answer (score 0):

because template is used by all rows.if name is usable .must have the same name in visual tree at one time.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an update to @Kolky's link as had to browse through a lot of MSDN Archives to find it.

[Visual Tree of a DataGrid - WPF DataGrid: Dissecting the Visual Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vinsibal/wpf-datagrid-dissecting-the-visual-layout)

P.S.: Low rep couldn't comment on Kolky's answer.